# Order by descending date - month, day and year

Tags: sql, sql-server

This seems stupid but, I simply need a list of dates to be ordered with the most recent date at top. Using `order by DESC` doesn't seem to be working the way I want it to.

```
SELECT     *
FROM         vw_view
ORDER BY EventDate DESC
```

It gives me the date ordered by month and day, but doesn't take year into consideration.
for example:

```
12/31/2009 

12/31/2008

12/30/2009

12/29/2009
```

Needs to be more like:

```
12/31/2009

12/30/2009

12/29/2009

12/28/2009
```

and so on.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `EventDate` column?

Comment: And the type of DB would be nice too

Comment: Why not updating you table design and make it correct, using a date field ?! Using workarounds for a poor design is not a good path.

Comment: @ConradFrix one might argue that the tag `sql-server` presumes Microsoft SQL Server. That said, it would _still_ be nice to know what the datatype of that column is...

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn seems form the question history I added the tag. Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676139/order-by-descending-date-month-day-and-year?noredirect=1#comment5154912_4676158) I did it when the OP confirmed the DB.

Comment: Oh! I stand corrected; sorry, I didn't check the history; I wrongly assumed that it was the OP who had self-tagged their answer. Thanks for your very valuable update :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I'm guessing `EventDate` is a char or varchar and not a date otherwise your order by clause would be fine.

You can use CONVERT to change the values to a date and sort by that

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     vw_view 
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(DateTime, EventDate,101)  DESC
```

The problem with that is, as Sparky points out in the comments, if EventDate has a value that can't be converted to a date the query won't execute.

This means you should either exclude the bad rows or let the bad rows go to the bottom of the results

To exclude the bad rows just add `WHERE IsDate(EventDate) = 1`

To let let the bad dates go to the bottom you need to use `CASE`

e.g.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE
       WHEN IsDate(EventDate) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DateTime, EventDate,101)
       ELSE null
    END DESC
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you! you were correct in assuming it is sql server and EventDate is set as a varchar

Comment: @user570457. No problem. I updated your tags to include SQL-Server. It a good idea to include it on the next question.

Comment: One caveat, if any of the dates are invalid, SQL will return an error on the convert, making your query invalid.   Can be frustrating since you have to figure out which date is causing the problem.  You can use IsDate() =0 to see if you have any invalid dates to worry about

Answer (score 21):

try `ORDER BY MONTH(Date),DAY(DATE)`

Try this:

`ORDER BY YEAR(Date) DESC, MONTH(Date) DESC, DAY(DATE) DESC`

Worked perfectly on a **JET DB**.

Answer (score 8):

You have the field in a string, so you'll need to convert it to datetime

```
order by CONVERT(datetime, EventDate ) desc
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you have the power to make schema changes the only acceptable answer to this question IMO is to change the base data type to something more appropriate (e.g. `date` if SQL Server 2008).

Storing dates as `mm/dd/yyyy` strings is space inefficient, difficult to validate correctly and makes sorting and date calculations needlessly painful.

Answer (score 4):

what is the type of the field `EventDate`, since the ordering isn't correct i assume you don't have it set to some Date/Time representing type, but a string. And then the american way of writing dates is nasty to sort

Comment: whoever set this up had the EventDate set as a varchar for some reason :/

Answer (score 4):

If you restructured your date format into YYYY/MM/DD then you can use this simple string ordering to achieve the formating you need.

Alternatively, using the [SUBSTR(store_name,start,length)](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html) command you should be able to restructure the sorting term into the above format

perhaps using the following

```
SELECT     *
FROM         vw_view
ORDER BY SUBSTR(EventDate,6,4) + SUBSTR(EventDate, 0, 5) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT     *
FROM  vw_view
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(EventDate, "%m-%d-%y") DESC
```