# Order by year in post date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My sql query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, PostDate), 1, 3) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(PostDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS PostArchive,
   Posts = COUNT(*) 
FROM    
   Post  WHERE Verified=1 
GROUP BY
   SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, PostDate), 1, 3) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(PostDate) AS VARCHAR(4)),
   YEAR(PostDate), MONTH(PostDate)

 ORDER BY PostArchive
```

Its gives a result like this:

```
PostArchive    Posts
------------------------
Mar-2009    1
Mar-2010    1
May-2005    1
May-2011    1
May-2012    1
May-2013    1
```

But I want a result order by date(year) like this.

```
PostArchive    Posts
------------------------
May-2005    1
Mar-2009    1
Mar-2010    1
May-2011    1
May-2012    1
May-2013    1
```

I search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676139/order-by-descending-date-month-day-and-year) link but unable to solve my problem.

I try :

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, PostArchive,101)  DESC
```

But it gives me a error:

`Invalid column name 'PostArchive'.`

Is there any way to do this or I am in wrong way.Thanks.

Comment: try Cast(PostArchive as datetime)

Comment: @Rob same error `Invalid column name ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `PostArchive` is the name you've given to the column on the SELECT line, which is effectively the output of the query. The ORDER BY clause does not look at that, it looks at its input to the query, which in this case is `PostDate`

Comment: I am not able to use `PostDate` in this case because `it is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Then order by the thing in the group by which uses PostDate then: `SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, PostDate), 1, 3) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(PostDate) AS VARCHAR(4))` or `YEAR(PostDate)`, or `MONTH(PostDate)`

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume that you didn't really mean that you want to order it by
   year, but instead by year/month. The ordering issue that you have is
   because you are ordering it as a character and not as a date.
2. You don't need DISTINCT, since you already GROUP BY.
3. Main problem is that you already converted to VARCHAR. Hence, months
   are unsortable.

ssss

```
-- Create a CTE (inline view)

WITH T AS (
SELECT YEAR(PostDate) PostYear
     , MONTH(PostDate) PostMM
     , SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, PostDate),1,3) PostMonth
     , COUNT(*) Posts
  FROM Post
 WHERE Verified = 1
 GROUP BY YEAR(PostDate)
     , MONTH(PostDate)
     , DATENAME(MONTH, PostDate)
)
 -- Build you date string
SELECT PostMonth + '-' + CAST(PostYear AS VARCHAR(4)) AS PostArchive
     , Posts
  FROM T
   -- Sort it by the components separately
 ORDER BY PostYear
  -- Don't use the character, otherwise, Aug will come before Mar
     , PostMM
```

Answer (score 0):

I used CTE to get the result try this

```
with tempTable (PostArchiveMonth , PostArchiveYear , PostArchiveMonthName ,  Posts )
(
    select month(PostDate) , YEAR(PostDate) , SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, PostDate), 1, 3) 
           COUNT(*) 
    FROM Post  
    WHERE Verified=1 
    group by MONTH(PostDate) ,YEAR( PostDate)
    ,SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, PostDate), 1, 3) 
)

select PostArchiveMonthName +'-' + PostArchiveYear as PostArchive , Posts
from  tempTable 
order by PostArchiveYear  , PostArchiveMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, PostDate), 1, 3) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(PostDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS PostArchive,
   Posts = COUNT(*) 
FROM    
   Post  WHERE Verified=1 
GROUP BY
   SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, PostDate), 1, 3) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(PostDate) AS VARCHAR(4)),
   YEAR(PostDate), MONTH(PostDate)
Order by Month(PostDate), Year(PostDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

`ORDER BY PostArchive`

...to this...

`ORDER BY YEAR(PostDate)`