# PHP MYSQL convert timezone aware dates to UTC

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am working on an existing scheduling application that stores appointment date/time in mysql as "2013-12-25 09:00:00".  No timezone is accounted for, as until now, that time is simply sent to the front end and displayed in some basic fashion.  Now, I would like to build in some functionality like "send a reminder X hours before the appt".  Obviously to do this I would need to know the time zone to determine if I am X hours before the appt.

I'm not really sure where to start now.  How would I convert my existing dates to UTC without knowing the timezone?  If I did collect the timezone info from my users, how would I go about converting existing mysql datetime format to UTC?  I also have questions about the general roundtrip workflow of working with UTC dates.  Here is how I would think it works:

1. Store all dates in UTC
2. Pass all dates to client in UTC
3. Let client apply offset for the user

When creating new appointments:

1. convert date / time to UTC based on users offset
2. store in UTC
3. restart process with #1

Is this accurate?  Thanks for any help, would like to do this properly, but not sure where to start with all these existing appts, and no timezone info :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organizing dates with times and timezones. (Converting to accurate timestamp.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752912/organizing-dates-with-times-and-timezones-converting-to-accurate-timestamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) datatype (as opposed to its `DATETIME` one) is internally stored in UTC.  Translation between that and the client's [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) is performed upon receiving data from / sending data to the client: one merely needs to set that variable at the start of the session:

```sql
SET time_zone = 'GMT';
```

As for converting existing times, you can utilise MySQL's [`CONVERT_TZ()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function:

```sql
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = CONVERT_TZ(my_column, 'GMT', 'MET');
```

Read more under [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time-zone-support.html).