# SQL get nearest date record

Tags: php, sql, yii

This is an sample data:

```
 Booking_id   Name   start_date
   1            abc   1/1/2018
   2            efg   5/2/2018
   3            pqr   16/1/2018
   4            xyz   19/2/2018
```

I want this is to be in order nearest to today date on top and past date in last

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: what is the datatype of `start_date` field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order by descending date - month, day and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676139/order-by-descending-date-month-day-and-year)

Comment: i am using mysql DB

Comment: start_date is of datetime datatype

Comment: Are dates in `start_date` always in the past?

Comment: no the are of any past,future or current

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `SORT` `desc` function on column `start_Date`. Below is the query which will produce your desired result.

```
select * from table1
order by Start_Date desc;
```

You can check sqlfiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c5332/1)

If the dates are in future,  you have to use `asc` to get your desired result.

```
select * from table1
order by Start_Date asc;
```

If your dates are mix of Past and future dates like below sample data.

```
ID Name   Start_Date
---------------------
1  abc   2018-01-01
2  efg   2018-02-05
3  pqr   2018-01-16
4  xyz   2018-02-19
1  abc   2017-01-01
2  efg   2017-02-05
3  pqr   2017-01-16
4  xyz   2017-02-19
```

Below query can be a option to show data in more friendly format.

```
select * from (
select * from table1
where start_date < current_date
order by start_date desc
) as B
union
select 0,'TODAY_DATE', current_date
union
select * from (
select * from table1
where start_date > current_date
order by start_date asc
) as A
```

It will sort past dates data in `desc` order, then add `TODAY` date to result and then add future data in `asc` format as below.

```
 ID  Name        Start_Date
--------------------------
4   xyz         2017-02-19
2   efg         2017-02-05
3   pqr         2017-01-16
1   abc         2017-01-01
0   TODAY_DATE  2017-08-18
1   abc         2018-01-01
3   pqr         2018-01-16
2   efg         2018-02-05
4   xyz         2018-02-19
```

check SQLfiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bc3d/9)

Comment: this return record in reverse order not the nearest date to today

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT Booking_id, Name, start_date
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(start_date, NOW()));
```

The `ORDER BY` clause sorts by the distance in days from today's date. The date having the smallest distance comes first.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/XZJPS95423)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ORDER BY` function of sql. Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     table_name 
ORDER BY 
   start_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding below would be your query, let me know further.

Use can use Order by with ASC|Desc based on requirement,

```
select * from booking_table order by start_date DESC;
```

Comment: this return record in reverse order by date  not the nearest record to today's date

Comment: Dear Paritosh, Reverse order from today means the same it will render the nearest records in descending order to today's date.

Answer (score 1):

You want nearest date from todate so you can try followuing query

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE start_date >= now()
ORDER BY start_date ASC;
```

**OR**

If you want it in revere order then:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE start_date <= now()
ORDER BY start_date DESC;
```

Comment: thank you for response it solve my half problem now i am getting  records from today's date but i want my old records to be append at the end how can i do that?

Comment: yes i have tried it without limit it returns records of today and from future but not the records having start_date < todays date i want this records to be at the end

Comment: You want all records? Today, future and past?

Comment: yes order will be like this- today's records follow by future  records and then old records at the end

Answer (score 1):

this works for you,

`select * from table_name Order By start_date Desc;`

Answer (score 1):

Based on one of your comments:

> today's records follow by future records and then old records at the
>   end

this will sort today and future dates first, followed by past dates:

```
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN start_date >= CURRENT_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
   start_date
```

Results in both new and old dates sorted ascending, if you want the old dates sorted descending:

```
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN start_date >= CURRENT_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
   ABS(CURRENT_DATE - start_date)
```