# Sort datagridview by newest c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a small program to store the values in a "datagridview". The problem is that the new value is hidden in the middle of the datagrid. I simply want the most recent "value" uploaded to be placed at the top of the data. So everytime someone uploads a new value, it should be stored in the top of the datagridview. Thanks.

https://gyazo.com/0f44611556133d8db60e66e910fd4fa3
https://gyazo.com/81a2996928b5f21f1aec5f20f9861b5d

```
        //Showing history
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT (Hund),(Vem),(Vad),(Datum),(Tid) FROM lexidatabase.dbo.tbl_rastad WHERE username = @Username";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Login.username;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sa.Fill(dt);
        historik.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
```

Comment: please, don't post image of code, and data as well if possible. See : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/479251

Comment: What is the item source of your datagrid ? you could sort the item source if you are using binding.

Comment: for example.
Select * from Account Order by Id desc

Comment: @Pac0 I'm sorry, I think I just fixed the issues

Comment: @Alexus How do I do that?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676139/order-by-descending-date-month-day-and-year

Comment: @snnbrn The problem is, I don't put any ID in it, because the application is an app to know what hour and minute I was out with my dog. So I basically just add information, like "what dog, name, date and time"

Comment: @snnbrn https://gyazo.com/39c9e9bfb28479d9dc70a1aa65c3cc53 I think I just solved the issue, now.. It looks very good, but the only problem is that the newest is placed all the way down on the list, instead of on top.

Comment: Order by Hund desc


----------
asc 123456 abcd
desc 654321 dcda

Comment: @snnbrn THANKS A LOT! I just figured out the way how I should use desc, which helped me with the issue! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @LolPrezy nice.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below,This is the way to sort a DGV in code, there is a methord called "Sort" in DataGridView

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Name"],ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Check this microsoft Definition  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sort?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_Sort_System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumn_System_ComponentModel_ListSortDirection_)

Comment: Try this after binding data to dataGridView

Comment: i think OP wants to sort by Datum & Tid

Comment: @PrathapG Like this? https://gyazo.com/2fb8d35bd86f3f02297bba77c9160a88

Comment: @PrathapG Not really, sadly :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the last addition at the top, you need an increased value or date of creation.

If you want to list the list by name or another field.

```
SELECT (Hund),(Vem),(Vad),(Datum),(Tid) FROM lexidatabase.dbo.tbl_rastad WHERE username = @Username Order By Hund,Vem,Datum asc
```

asc or desc you can use.

```
Order By Hund,Vem,Datum asc

Order By Hund asc

Order By Datum asc

Order By Tid asc
```

ı hope i cold help

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add new column in your table, like [Creation Date], [Date Add] or something like that, then in your query, you can use ORDER BY clause.

```
ORDER BY [Creation Date] DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY [Date Add] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from **"snn brn**" which is.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT (Hund),(Vem),(Vad),(Datum),(Tid) 
FROM lexidatabase.dbo.tbl_rastad WHERE username = @Username ORDER BY (Datum) desc,(Tid) desc";
```

So bascially you have to order it by the `datum(date)` and `tid(time)` and then add `desc` at the end of it. Then the list will add the new actions on the top, and also in order.